# Ng-repeat rendering entire list from the beginnning after appending items to it

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am implementing infinite-scrolling using Angular. When the user reaches the end of scroll, new data are fetched using an Ajax call, and appended to the existing list. Here is the relevant code:

Function that gets called on successful completion of AJAX call:

```
function successCallBack(data){
     var scope = angular.element($("#splistroot")).scope();
     scope.$apply(function(){
      if(scope.providersList === null) {
           scope.providersList = []; /* init if null */
        }

        Array.prototype.push.apply(scope.providersList, JSON.parse(data.serviceproviderlist));
        scope.serviceName = data.category;
        scope.limit += SEARCH_LIMIT;
        viewToBeDisplayed(LIST_VIEW);
     })
     setEvents();
     if (A.onScreen(listEndDiv,10)) {
          getMoreDataEnd();
     }
  }
```

HTML part:

```
<div id="spn-service-provider-list">
    <div ng-repeat="providersList in ( filteredproducts = ( providersList | filter:{ providerName: spsearch } | filter:{ citiesServicing: locationsearch }:ignoreNullComparator ))  | orderBy: 'rank' | limitTo: limit" >
    ......
    .......
```

The problem I am facing is that ng-repeat is rendering the entire list from the starting, each time **successCallBack()** is called. I want to show the appended data, just like most websites do. Is there any solution to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could use a nested list?  An outer ng-repeat for pages, and an inner ng-repeat for items.  Each time you get to the bottom, ask the server for a new page, and add it to your list.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit further on that?

Comment: @KarlWenzel My server currently returns data as JSON.

Comment: My thought was that each Ajax call (i.e. page) can be treated as its own list, however I'm taking a closer look at your filter and rethinking that approach.  I believe your list is re-rendering each time because it is being sorted by the filter on each successCallBack().

Comment: That is a very nice thought. Let me remove the filters and update you when I have access to my computer again. Should be in 30 minutes.

Comment: @KarlWenzel the thing is, the scroll bar moves all the way to top on each render.

Comment: @KarlWenzel I removed the sorting thing. Still, to no avail )-:

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure.  I tried recreating a simpler case on Plunker, but it does not reset the vertical scroll position like you describe: https://plnkr.co/edit/s7qWFEmry3BOV8o7rW5T?p=preview .

Comment: When the data loads, I tried putting a small buffering icon at the end of the list, and boom, the list appears as expected.